# Access AutoNumber sequence changed after Compact & Repair

Tags: ms-access

I've an access db and I modified some tables using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN ID AUTOINCREMENT(1001,1)
```

This table has first column ID as autonumber.   I did a compact & repair after the table is created. But while inserting data the first id is set to 1 and not 1001. If I don't do a compact repair the first Id is set to 1001 as expected. I don't have any control over when the compact repair will be executed. So is there a way to make sure that the ID starts at 1001 always ?

Comment: Don't rely on the value of an autoincrement column in Access or the value of a sequence-generated ID in Oracle or an autoincrement column in SQL Server to be anything more than just a meaningless unique number. In Access a compact and repair resets the start value, and you will generate gaps every time you dirty but do not commit a new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An autonumber's seed value is not static.  As soon as you add a row, the seed is reset to the previous seed value plus the increment.

An intentional feature with compact is to reset the seed based on the current values contained in the autonumber field.

There is no simple easy workaround.

You could create an `autoexec` macro to check your autonumber's current seed value and execute your DDL statement if it's less than 1001.  That would set it as you wish each time you open the database.

Or you could add a dummy row to `TestTable` with ID = 1000, and make sure you never delete that row.  But that's ugly.

Or you could make ID Long Integer and create your own custom auto-numbering code to determine the value you store there.  But that's not easy or convenient.